# SilverStripe 3: Get ID of Parent DataObject in child's onAfterWrite()

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 2.4, I was able to get ID of parent DataObject "A" in onAfterWrite() method of child dataobject "B" by

```
$this->AClassID
```

How to get "A"'s ID in "B"'s onAfterWrite() method ?

Note:"A" has many "B"s and "B" has one "A" (one-to-many relationship).

Sample code here for kind consideration:

http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/507d5222878a7

Comment: could you please post your code, just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if statement to make sure it is not 0 before continuing. like

```
if($this->ID){
 //put all your code here
}
```

Or

```
if($this->RelationName()->ID){
 //put all your code here
}
```

The reason is that it is called multiple times and you just need to execute when it is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$this->AClass->ID`. Or if you have a `Parent` relationship setup in your `has_one` ie

```
public static $has_one=array(
    'Parent'=>'AClass'
);
```

you could use `$this->Parent->ID`.

Comment: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/507d5222878a7
Here is code for kind consideration. When I comment out onAfterWrite() of MatchDate, then it works fine. Otherwise query where it try to get ID of Match Class causes problem. Because I am unable to get MatchID(parent).

Comment: I have tried the solution mentioned in your code but unable to get ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$this->Parent()->ID
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.